# Finite index subfactors of hyperfinite type $\mathrm{III}_{\lambda}$ factors

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a hyperfinite type $\mathrm{III}_\lambda$ factor. $N$ be a finite index type $\mathrm{III}$ subfactor, is it true $N$ is hyperfinite type $\mathrm{III}_{\lambda}$?